# Ubuntu on USB and WIndows 8 on HDD - What can go wrong?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-8, usb

I want to put Ubuntu on a USB, but I am not sure if there is any possible compatibility issues with a Windows 8 laptop.  In other words, if I install Ubuntu on a USB stick and use it to run Ubuntu on a laptop that has Windows 8 installed - what could go wrong?

I have a Ubuntu pen drive, but that doesn't allow me to save any changes (such as adding/removing packages).  I noticed that when I boot into Ubuntu on the USB, the computer's clock changes to a different time zone and that this change shows up the next time I boot into Windows.  So I can see that my Linux OS is having some effect on my Windows OS.

In order to be safe, I would prefer to install Ubuntu on a USB stick using a MacBook Pro with Linux Mint installed.  That way, if I goof up, the damage would be done to my home computer (the mac) and not my work computer (the pc).  However, I'm not sure if the OS install detects onboard hardware and configures accordingly.  BOth the mac and pc have UEFI booting, and not BIOS.

So what could go wrong, and what should I do to prevent that?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing would go wrong really - your Linux installation isn't actually affecting your Windows installation, it's affecting the date and time stored in the BIOS. There isn't much more it would do without your intervention in doing so.

In order to keep any packages and data you save, look into installing Linux on a USB in `persistent mode`. This will save changes you make and should stop resetting your clock every boot.

[Further reading on installing Ubuntu USB persistent](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent)